# Debian postfix mail server

Tags: debian, postfix-mta, dovecot

We have Debian 6 email server deployed with Postfix , Dovecot , Roundcube . All users stored as virtual users in mysql database. We have to migrate to Debian 7. I was wondering if it would be possible to setup fresh debian 7 with postfix config, dovecot and roundcube and then just migrate mysql users from old system and there mail directory? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, but it will be difficult for people to give you specific instructions  without knowing exactly how you configured all the services to work together when you originally installed then (e.g. did you work from a tutorial, keep any notes etc?)

This (rather old) guide to **[migrating user accounts](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/)** may help (refer to the comments).

I would have thought it would be considerably easier to first attempt to just **[upgrade the existing server](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html)** providing you have (a) backed it up properly (b) don't mind the downtime during the upgrade.

Note: I've seen [one tutorial](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/system/os/debian-squeeze-to-wheezy-distupgrade) mention there is a problem with upgrading Dovecot and a workaround is to uninstall (fully purge) it, upgrade Debian then reinstall it again.